# keyfob cc2541 bluetooth connection drops when trying to enable acclerometer on android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an Android app that needs to read the Keyfob's Accelerometer data. Until now I've followed this tutorial: https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1553/bluetooth_smart_le_android_tutorial

With it I was able to connect with the Keyfob, search for services and read some characteristics. The problem is when I try to enable the keyfob's Accelerometer, the bluetooth connection simply drops.

This is the code I use to try to enable the accelerometer:

```
private void enableAccelerometer(BluetoothGatt gatt){
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
        BluetoothGattService service;
        Log.d(TAG, "ligando acelerometro");
        service = gatt.getService(ACCELEROMETER_SERVICE);
        if(service == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Not able to find the service");
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "Service found");
            characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(ENABLE_ACCELEROMETER);
            if(characteristic == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic not found");
            }
            else{
                characteristic.setValue(new byte[] {0x01});
                if (!gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "writing failed ");
                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "writing successful:  ");
                }
            }
        }
```

This method is called in the "onServicesDiscovered" callback function.

The Texas Instrument CC2540/41 Mini Development Kit User’s Guide states that to enable the accelerometer it is necessary to write "01" in the enable acceleromenter characteristic in the accelerometer serivce, that's what I am doing with this code.

The connection between the phone (LG G2 mini running Android 4.4.2) drops when I write:

```
  characteristic.setValue(new byte[] {0x01});
```

I am sure it is this line that is making the connection drop, if I comment it out or simply try to write a string instead of a byte, the connection doesn't drop.

Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that after a week I found a way to turn the accelerometer on. I still don't know why it is working only that way, but I just changed:

`characteristic.setValue(new byte[] {0x01});`

to

```
characteristic.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
```

I don't know what value is exactly inside the "BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE" constant, but it worked.

Comment: The value for `BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE` is `{0x01, 0x00}`. See [BluetoothGattDescriptor source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattDescriptor.java).

Comment: Thanks Pedo Rates, it helps me alot. I have one more issue. I am unable to read X,Y,Z notification. I have searched but did not get any clue.